# Vlc video architecture

Tags: vlc, libvlc, vlc-qt

I am studying the VLC source code in order to understand where exactly VLC writes the decoded frame to the screen. I'm basically interested in the qt ui version, and the windows and linux platforms.

I have come as far as tracing from `avcodec_decode_video2` up until the point where it writes the frame to a queue using `vout_PutPicture` and `picture_fifo_Push`. On the other end, I see there is a `Thread` object that calls `ThreadDisplayRenderPicture`, which in turn calls `vout_display_Display`, which calls `Display`. I expected this last function to be the one where the bytes for the video frame actually get copied to the frame buffer, but all it does is set the size, and then release the picture.

Could someone explain to me, or point me to a resource that does, where exactly does VLC writes the `picture_t` structure that is sitting in the queue to the WId structure, effectively writing the frame to the screen? Any link to a more thorough explanation of VLC's video architecture would be great too!

Answer (score 8):

I cannot directly answer your question, but provide you with a reference to a thorough explanation of VLC's architecture. (As stated in your last sentence)

Christophe Massiot from the University of Klagenfurt has written a paper on the VLC media player API Documentation. You can find it on google [here](https://svn-itec.uni-klu.ac.at/trac2/dash/export/24/trunk/documentation/vlc_manual.pdf) and on google scholar [here](https://scholar.google.at/scholar?cluster=5791386869307511242&hl=en&as_sdt=0,5).

It includes the following illustration, which may lead you in the right direction.

[image: VLC Architecture]

I think the document could prove useful to your question. Take a look at Chapter 5 describing the video output layer

Comment: Thank you very much, Michael! That is what I was looking for! It's too bad I don't have the reputation to accept your answer, because you certainly pointed me to the material that I needed. Thanks again.

Comment: @user3846684 glad I could help; please try accepting the answer again, there should be no reputation minimum to accepting answers (see: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234), only to upvoting answers. Thank you!